# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier, blobServiceClient: any;

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, constructor, azure-blob-storage

**I am Creating a class that will generate a sasurl which I need to upload a file to the front-end. I will use the class BlobStorageApi in other modules to create APIs. But when I run this code I am getting SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. This code was not in class before and was working but after I put it in a class it is giving me an error.

```
const storage = require("@azure/storage-blob");

class BlobStorageAPI {
  blobServiceClient: any;
    containerName: string;
    client: any;
    blobName: string;
    blobClient: any;
    creds: any;
  constructor(account, accountKey, accountName) {
    const creds = new storage.StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);
    this.blobServiceClient = new storage.BlobServiceClient(
      `https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net`,
      creds
    );
    this.containerName = 'text'
    this.client = this.blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(this.containerName)
    this.blobName = 'help.txt'
    this.blobClient = this.client.getBlobClient(this.blobName)
  }

  get blobSAS() {
    return storage
      .generateBlobSASQueryParameters({
        containerName:this.containerName,
        blobName: this.blobName,
          permissions: storage.BlobSASPermissions.parse("racwd"),
          startsOn: new Date(),
          expiresOn: new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 86400),
        },
        this.creds
      ).toString();
  }
  get sasUrl() {
    return this.blobClient.url + "?" + this.blobSAS;
  }
}

const api = new BlobStorageAPI('joey','/Zs0kjnFoKtKqDPdiAV/61+pTdRhr5H5Wd5vQheXoEtuTOjtWLp6w==', "blobstorage0420");
console.log(api.blobSAS);
console.log();
console.log(api.sasUrl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try the code:**

```
const storage = require("@azure/storage-blob");

class BlobStorageAPI {

  constructor(accountName, accountKey) {
    this.creds = new storage.StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
    this.blobServiceClient = new storage.BlobServiceClient(
      `https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net`,
      this.creds
    );
    this.containerName = 'your-container-name'
    this.client = this.blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(this.containerName)
    this.blobName = 'your-blob-name'
    this.blobClient = this.client.getBlobClient(this.blobName)
  }

  get blobSAS() {
    return storage
      .generateBlobSASQueryParameters({
        containerName:this.containerName,
        blobName: this.blobName,
          permissions: storage.BlobSASPermissions.parse("racwd"),
          startsOn: new Date(),
          expiresOn: new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 86400),
        },
        this.creds
      ).toString();
  }

  get sasUrl() {
    // console.log(this.blobName, this.containerName)
    return this.blobClient.url + "?" + this.blobSAS;
  }
}

const account = "storage-account-name";
const key = "account-key";

const api = new BlobStorageAPI(account, key);
console.log(api.blobSAS);
console.log();
console.log(api.sasUrl);
```

**What do I do:**

1. Delete `blobServiceClient: any;...`
2. Change `const creds` with `this.creds`
3. Change to `StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey)`, delete `account` in your code.

**Result:**

[image]

For more details about constructor in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor